# Do book drops happen in Adventure mode?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Trying to pick up some achievements such as book drops, aside from some "same location different time" book drops, such as leah's diaries is it possible to find the books in adventure mode?

Answer (score 1):

Many of them, yes, but not all of them. You will have to play in Story mode at least once if you want to find all of the lore books.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any of the books required for the achievement can be dropped in adventure mode, given that you are in the area where the book drop. Note that some of these books are more rare than others and might take several resets (leave game > create new game) before getting them.

Comment: There are a few other books that only appear during a specific quest (if my memory serves me right there is one of those in early act 4 in the basetown near the closed gate on the north side.)